# Find parametric defined arc length

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The task is to find length of a curve which is defined with following equations:

$$
x=3t \;
y=3t^2 \;
z=2t^3
$$
from point $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,3,2)$.

I've tried using following integral formula:
$$\int^{t=1}_{t=0}\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2+(z'(t))^2}dt \\=
3\cdot\int^{t=1}_{t=0}\sqrt{1+4t^2+4t^4}dt =\\
\int^{t=1}_{t=0}(2t^2+1)dt=5,$$ however answer is $7/3$, is there any mistake in calculations or idea of the whole solution should be different?

Comment: I agree with your computations, could be a typo in the answer?

Comment: There is a typo in the answer. I did the calculation and the result is the same of yours.

Comment: 3 is missing before the last integral, but it doesn't change 5.